# Sum of a column based on a subgroup from another column in datatable r

Tags: r, data.table

Considering a sample `data.table`,

`dt = data.table(A = c(1:5), B = c("a","b","c","a","b"))`

I would want to `sum` the column A based on column "B", but with a subgroup of `c("a","b")` and `"c"`. i.e, the output should look like

```
c("a","b")= 12
"c"   =     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert `B` into factor and then change the levels to do this:

```
#convert B to factor
dt[, B := factor(B)]
#change levels to ab and c
levels(dt$B) <- c('ab', 'ab', 'c')
#group and sum
dt[, sum(A), by = B]
#    B V1
#1: ab 12
#2:  c  3
```

Or as an alternative as per @akrun 's comment you could do:

```
dt[, .(B = paste(unique(B), collapse=""), A = sum(A)), 
   .(grp = B %in% c('a', 'b'))][, grp := NULL][]
```

Or as per @Frank 's comment:

```
mDT = unique(dt[, "B"])[, g := B][B %in% c("a","b"), g := "ab"]
dt[mDT, on=.(B)][, sum(A), by=g]
```

Comment: That's a nice one @akrun . Why don't you post it as a new one? It is only done in one call as well!

Comment: It's okay, you can add it in your post as this may have some dupes

Comment: Nice solution by `factor` ~ +1

Comment: I'd do `mDT = unique(dt[, "B"])[, g := B][B %in% c("a","b"), g := "ab"]; dt[mDT, on=.(B)][, sum(A), by=g]` since I like having the grouping of a & b stored in an explicit object (mDT here). Feel free to add if you want. (Like akrun, I guess I've posted my suggestion a few times before.)